# How does google analytics count IE browsers?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-analytics

When I present `<meta content="IE=8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">` in the `<head>` and I go to the site with IE9 will I effectively count IE8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics determines the user's browser based on the user-agent string sent with the request for `http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif`.

The user-agent string won't be affected by the meta tag in you mentioned, so the answer is no, you would count as IE9 in that situation.

Comment: ok so X-UA-Compatible does not affect the UA presented to the outside?